# python is not converting the str value in int while using text_box.get() (in Tkinter )

Tags: python, tkinter

in following code I am trying to fetch the value in text box(in tkinter window). after fetching that I want to convert the same value in int as it is in str.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='gray75')
root.title("Simple Calculator")

text_box = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=7)
text_box.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=20)


result = 0


def button_add(result):
    text_box.delete(0, END)
    second_num = text_box.get()
    s_num = int(second_num)
    result += s_num
    return result
```

But I am getting an unexpected error (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '')
Please help me with this. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Please show the code that calls `button_add`. It is almost certainly the case where you're calling the function before the user has a chance to enter any data.

Answer (score 1):

hi your `second_num` is `null`. to avoid this you must assign a default value like this

```
def button_add(result):
    text_box.delete(0, END)
    if second_num=="":
       second_num=0
    second_num = text_box.get()
    s_num = int(second_num)
    result += s_num
    return result
```

I hope to help you...